# Как записать данные в БД через цикл while?

Tags: php, mysqli

Добрый вечер всем!
у меня есть цикл,который записывает данные в БД через while()
($id известно ранее)

```
    $i = 1;

while (isset($_POST['account-'.$i]) && isset($_POST['brokerage-id-'.$i])) {

    $account = $_POST['account-'.$i.''];
    $brokerage = $_POST['brokerage-id-'.$i.''];

    echo $_POST['account-'.$i.''];
    echo $_POST['brokerage-id-'.$i.''];
    echo $id;

    $res = $db->query("INSERT INTO `accounts` SET `id_user` = '".$id."', `account` = '".$account."', `brokerage` = '".$brokerage."'") or exit(mysql_error());
    $i++;
}
```

echo выводит все правильно, но запись в БД попадает только одна(самая первая),а последующие - нет, только echo показывает,что итерации проходят и выводит значения всех итерации

Comment: А что такое `$id`?

Comment: $id - это ид пользователя, оно известно ранее, и при итерации вывод одно и тоже значение(думал,что оно тоже будет менятся)

Comment: Само ничего не происходит. вы должны сами за ним следить раз уж не используете возможности автоматической нумерации на стороне БД (а для этого не надо вообще упоминать id в запросе, ну и что бы колонка была автоинкремент). А вообще после любого обращения к БД надо проверять код завершения и печатать ошибки если их БД вернула

Comment: есть вероятность что в БД поле id проверяется на уникальность или еще что. Покажите show create table accounts

Comment: спасибо за ответы) я нашел причину)